# Getting redirected to another webpage on page load with the contents of my JavaScript array as the URL

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing a small exercise using HTML and Javascript. Basically, I have 2 input fields that I need to validate using 1 function in Javascript. 
The first input asks for the name and if the name is less than 3 characters, there would be an error printed, else, the error is removed. 
The second one asks for the locality. Now, to validate this, I must first create an array which contains about 3 locations and then compare the location the user entered to see if it is in the array. If it is not, again, an error is printed. The thing is this; I am getting an error on live preview. 
The error prints "Cannot GET /Msida,Pieta,Marsa" on screen and "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" on the console. What could the problem be?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Revision</title>
</head>

    <body>
        <nav id="menu"></nav>
        <a>Full Name: </a><input type="text" name="fName" id="fName" ><br/>
        <div id="divName"></div><br/>
        <a>Locality: </a><input type="text" name="locality" id="locality" ><br/>
        <div id="divLocality"></div><br/>
        <script src="js/mainScript.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/detailsScript.js"></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var fName = document.getElementById("fName");
var locality = document.getElementById("locality");
var divName = document.getElementById("divName");
var divLocality = document.getElementById("divLocality");
var location = ["Msida", "Pieta", "Marsa"];


function validation()
{
if(this.name == "fName")
    {
        if(this.value.length < 3)
            {
                divName.innerHTML = "Name should have atleast 3 characters";
                divName.style.color = "red";
            }
        else if(this.value.length >= 3)
            {
                divName.innerHTML = "";
            }
    }
else if(this.name == "locality")
    {
        if(location.indexOf(this.value) > -1)
        {
            divLocality.innerHTML = "Location Exists";
            divLocality.style.color = "red";
        }
        else
        {
            divLocality.innerHTML = "Location doesn't Exist";
            divLocality.style.color = "red";
        }
    }

}

fName.addEventListener('focusout', validation);
locality.addEventListener('focusout', validation);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just rename your `location` variable. Your current code is not working because you are basically re-assigning the URL. See [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location).

JavaScript will actually execute  `var location = ['a', 'b', 'c'];` in 2 parts, declaration and assignment. The declaration part (`var location`) will be simply ignored because `location` is always declared initially (at least in the browser). And the re-assignment part (`location = ....`) will redirect you to `location.toString`.

Comment: That worked perfectly!! Didn't even come to my mind that that was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @jms15 I am going to confess, it feeled a bit weird to because naturally I just ignored the variable declarations and thought it had something to do with the functions. But I was not in my optimal mode either (sleepy).

Comment: @jms15 And you should understand that the best way to say thanks is to hit the `accept` button, which is not worth anything really, just satisfying.

Comment: I actually don't like this "function hidden behind assignment" thing at all, makes you wonder if it is frowned upon ?

Answer (score 2):

Use an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

> **IIFE** (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) is a JavaScript
>   function that runs as soon as it is defined.
>
> It is a design pattern which is also known as *Self-Executing Anonymous
>   Function* and contains two major parts. The first is the anonymous
>   function with lexical scope enclosed within the Grouping Operator ().
>   This prevents accessing variables within the IIFE idiom as well as
>   polluting the global scope.

Your location variable is conflicting with the `window.location` variable that stores the URL of the webpage the user is on - e.g. doing `location.assign('https://www.google.co.in')` or `location = "https://www.google.co.in"` will take you to Google's homepage.

Instead, doing it inside an IIFE like so:

```
(function() {
    var location = ["Msida", "Pieta", "Marsa"];
})();
```

will create the `location` variable without overwriting the one in the global scope.

Comment: He/she wouldn't be able to access that variable afterwards anyways.

Comment: Anonymous function right? I could have done it that way... Though I just renamed the variable. Thanks though!

Comment: Not just the function; the grouping operator `()` is also important. The first set of parentheses define a scope in which the function exists; omit them and the function becomes global. The second set of parentheses execute the function defined within(in which you can also pass any arguments which become arguments to the function inside). Also, you can take the second set of parentheses inside the first set, that's also valid - `(function() {...}());`